# How to create a "multi setup wizard bar" in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to set a "wizard bar" which will show the steps of a setup process like below .

[image]

So if I am in the second stage of the wizard, then 2 buttons will be filled etc. However button filling and all I can do manually (which means it do not have to work with the wizard step automatically) but I'm not sure how to implement such.

I'm currently on `ViewPager`. Any ideas?

**mylayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void updateIndicators(int position) {
       DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
       int resizeValue = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
             TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, metrics);
       int defaultValue = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
             TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, metrics);
       switch (position) {
       case 0:
          indicator1.getLayoutParams().height = resizeValue;
          indicator1.getLayoutParams().width = resizeValue;
          indicator1.requestLayout();

          indicator2.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator2.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator2.requestLayout();

          indicator3.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator3.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator3.requestLayout();

          indicator4.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator4.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator4.requestLayout();

          break;

       case 1:
          indicator1.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator1.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator1.requestLayout();

          indicator2.getLayoutParams().height = resizeValue;
          indicator2.getLayoutParams().width = resizeValue;
          indicator2.requestLayout();

          indicator3.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator3.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator3.requestLayout();

          indicator4.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator4.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator4.requestLayout();
          break;

       case 2:
          indicator1.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator1.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator1.requestLayout();

          indicator2.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator2.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator2.requestLayout();

          indicator3.getLayoutParams().height = resizeValue;
          indicator3.getLayoutParams().width = resizeValue;
          indicator3.requestLayout();

          indicator4.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator4.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator4.requestLayout();
          break;

       case 3:
          indicator1.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator1.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator1.requestLayout();

          indicator2.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator2.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator2.requestLayout();

          indicator3.getLayoutParams().height = defaultValue;
          indicator3.getLayoutParams().width = defaultValue;
          indicator3.requestLayout();

          indicator4.getLayoutParams().height = resizeValue;
          indicator4.getLayoutParams().width = resizeValue;
          indicator4.requestLayout();
          break;
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.androidsrc.viewpagerindicator.MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/indicator1"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/indicator_bg" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/indicator2"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/indicator_bg" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/indicator3"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/indicator_bg" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/indicator4"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/indicator_bg" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>


Make indicator view in xml like this.
```